# Chat online using Bitcoin addresses?

Tags: development, privacy, alternatives, trust, websites

I was surfing on the web and trying to find a chat app that uses Bitcoin address instead of phone numbers or any other identifier. Do you know about any project in this field?

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea. Addresses are not intended to be long-term persistent identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea was around for some time, and as Pieter mentioned, using addresses without any additional obfuscating seems like a bad implementation.

There are few other projects, the one that is most serious is [Microsoft's ION decentralized identity project](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/microsofts-ion-is-an-open-source-bet-on-bitcoin). It's not the chat-app itself, rather the way of signing into apps using bitcoin-generated identity.

When it comes to chat apps, there is a pretty rapid development in the field of lightning network. As messages on LN are onion-routed, it seem to be a good idea for privacy-preserving communication.
There are two projects I heard about, self-custodial [Juggernaut](https://www.getjuggernaut.com/) and centralized (so what's the point) [Sphinx](https://sphinx.chat/).

I'd be very hesitant in using these solutions, they are working as untested, beta-version projects, so they may not be as stable and secure.